# SmtpClient "Unable to read data from transport connection" only happens after x amount of emails are sent

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient, smtp-auth

Edit: Things I have tried

1. On the server running smtp in smpt virtual server I have set IP
   address to specific IP and to "all unassigned", in the Access tab of
   SMTP Virtual Service, under relay tab, I have added all the IPs to
   grant list along with 127.0.0.1
2. client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 100;
3. moved the using (creating of client) to inside of the for loop

Still same problem, 300 seems to be the magic number before it craps out

---

I have a very extremely weird problem that I have been trying to solve for past week.  My task is simple, "send bulk mail", so I created a very simple exe that will send bunch of emails to a gmail account.
After about sending 280, the sending fails with the following error: I have tried both port 587 and 25 and the problem happens on both ports

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
net_io_connectionclosed.
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 
offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, 
Boolean oneLine)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Now I will note that if i run the exe again RIGHT after it fails and i try to send ONE email, i get the same error so the issue does not seem to be a coding issue.  This is being sent on VPS running windows 2016 and SmarterMail 16 smtp server.

If i wait about an hour and try to send again, i can successfully send another 280. It seems there is some sort of throttling happening somewhere (I already turned off all the throttlings in SmarterMail).

What is weird is, right after it fails, if i use a service like https://www.smtper.net/ and use the same exact settings as i am using in my exe, then the email goes through with out any errors.  I am not sure if this is a smtp error, some setting on windows 2016 that wont allow more than x an hour etc.

Below is my actual exe code, as you can see its extremely simple example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many emails do you want to send?");
        var emailCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("How many seconds do you want to delay between each send");
        var delay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.WriteLine("What email address do you want to send to");
        var toEmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"Sending out {emailCount} with {delay} second delay to  {toEmailAddress}");

        using (var client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"]))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= emailCount; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var body = "this is a test message";
                    var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
                    var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                    client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
                    //client.EnableSsl = true;

                    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"]);

                    mailMessage.To.Add(toEmailAddress);
                    mailMessage.Body = body;
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    mailMessage.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subject"];

                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                    if (delay > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping...");

                        Thread.Sleep(delay * 1000);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"Email number {i} was sent successfully.");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send {i} of {emailCount}");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());


                }

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done...press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: If you send a large quantity of email to/from the same email address with the same content from the same smtp server it seems reasonable for GMail to decide to impolitely kill the connection for a while.

Comment: Problem doesnt seem to be with gmail, for example i just sent 300 to a gmail account, 280 passed and the rest failed.  Stopped the exe, ran the exe, this time i sent ONE email to a hotmail account, still got the same error.  
I tried sending to different email accounts with different domains, same problem.  Something somewhere is throttling the amount I can send and I cant seem to find where this is (smartermail settings all say I have removed throttling).  What is weird is that if i send it from the same server i get error, but if i use the same smtp settings from my local machine then it ok

Comment: If using .NET Core it maybe due to the QUIT command not being send on dispose.  See issue at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34868 for more information.